xpath to YouTube Subscribers is not working for me
I want to get the number of subscribers of a YouTube Channel into a Google Sheet without using the YouTube API.
I want to export youtube subscribers count in Google Sheets.
In a Google Sheet I tried with IMPORTXML like these:
=IMPORTXML($A1,"//meta[@property='og:description']/@content")
But none of them is working for me
For eg:
https://www.youtube.com/@youtube
For this URL, i want 41.4M subscribers in the Google sheets
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

According to grep, there is no alternative to parsing ytInitialData JavaScript JSON encoded string, see https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/0d3ef75ce6b69387ae2610dd3a384527848e352f/channels.php#L339.
